# Working Offline with Azure Table Storage on OSX / Node

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm aware of the [Azure Storage Emulator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/) available on Windows, however I'm wonder if anyone knows of a solution for developing against Azure Tables when using node on a Mac. I'm thinking of using [the official microsoft npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage), but see no mention of offline support.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a follow up to this question four years later! I ended up not using Azure Storage for a number of reasons. Not the least because of the offline / cross platform story. Instead I've done a couple of large scale projects in PostgreSQL using a combination of relational tables and the incredible JSONB. It's amazing. I've worked with SQL Server for over 20 years and I'm blown away by how much I'm loving Postgres. With regards to local dev, I run multiple postgres servers in Docker! Some for 'the app', others for integration tests. The tests even run in Azure Devops CICD!! It's fantastic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, offline development on Mac isn't a supported scenario of the emulator. You may be able to use a NetRedirector or something similar to set up the emulator on another machine and then access those ports from a Mac on your local network, but that sounds like that might not help in your scenario.

The client library that you linked to is able to send requests to the Emulator for offline support -- they're sort of independent in that sense -- but the Emulator needs to be run on Windows.

Comment: Thanks very much Peter.

Answer (score 5):

[Azurite](https://github.com/azure/azurite) is an open source implementation of the Azure Storage Emulator protocol that works on macOS.

It should be as simple as installing it with `npm install -g azurite` and running it with `azurite`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had some success running a Windows 10 virtual machine using VirtualBox on my mac.  I run the Azure Storage Emulator inside the virtual machine.  The necessary "tricks" are: -

1. You need to configure networking in VirtualBox (or your other virtualization product) so that the host and guest OS can communicate as if they are 2 hosts on the same network.
2. Configure the firewall on the Windows virtual machine so that it allows the connections you need (I needed port 10002 for Azure table storage).
3. Edit the storage emulator config file so that it binds to the actual IP address of the Windows VM that your Mac uses to communicate with it.  By default it binds to 127.0.0.1 which can only be accessed by clients running on the Windows VM.

Also, don't forget that the storage emulator needs some kind of SQL Server instance to be installed on the Windows VM.

That all sounds harder than it is, and it works for me in an "offline" situation.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have VirtualBox and Parallels set up. The only issue is that I use my mac a lot on the road and don't like running VM's more than necessary to save the battery. Good solution though :-)